# Why is this not a mad family?

Tags: set-theory

I'm a student trying to understand mad families, so please forgive my naivety.

Why is the following not a mad (maximal almost disjunct) family?

[image]

If you continue this infinitely, every group has infinite elements and there are infinite groups.
It seems to be almost disjunct (between any two groups the only intersection is the 1) and maximal (every natural number is used, so you can't add any other groups with infinite elements, that haven't already been used)

What am I missing?

Comment: Consider the "diagonal": $\{1,4,10,20,\dots\}$. It intersects each of your groups in at most two elements.

Comment: Is this supposed to be almost disjoint rather than disjunct? Also, what context is this being studied? I dont think sequence and series is a good tag and group theory is definitely not a good tag(I suspect some sort of set theory).

Comment: @Wojowu That should be an answer.

Comment: To the OP, to elaborate on Paul Plummer's comment note that [group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) is a particular topic - you're using the word "group" here in the natural-language sense, but it's a technical term unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed an almost disjoint family, but - as Wojowu observed above - it is not maximal.

Your argument for maximality ("every natural number is used, so you can't add any other groups with infinite elements, that haven't already been used") really just demonstrates that no set is disjoint from every set in your family. But it doesn't show that no set is *almost* disjoint from every set in your family.

Indeed, we can show that **no** countable almost disjoint family is maximal. Suppose $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an almost disjoint family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, let $a_i$ be (say) the smallest element of $A_i$ which is not in any $A_j$ for $j<i$; since the $A_i$s are almost disjoint, such an element exists. Now consider $$B=\{a_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ $B$ is almost disjoint from each of the $A_i$s - in particular, $\vert A_i\cap B\vert\le i$.